# My sister has gone Puzzled again

Tags: word, story, grid-deduction, poetry, affix-riddle

I once got a letter from my younger sister. It reads :-

> Hello brother,
>
> How are you? I am fine. I have seen you have given me a lot of gifts, thank you for that. Here's a present from my side. Since I like puzzles, I am giving you 3 notes with the letter as well. Do check it if you want. Happy Puzzling, hope you enjoy !
>
> Yours loving sister, Katie..

I think this made me obvious that today won't be a good day for me, I have to solve those annoying puzzles of hers again, giving gifts were always not so easy.

I already have 3 notes with the letter, so I opened the 1st one.

> I opened the first note, and it reads :-
>
> Hello, so this is the first part of the puzzle. I won't give you any clue, but here's a picture, that's it. Can you make some idea out of it?
>
> [image]

What the hell, I am not in a mood of solving this. Perhaps I will do it later, I need to make out what my sister means with these jiggly numbers and squares and all. I proceed opening the 2nd note.

> I opened the second note, it says :-
>
> Hello, I hope you have already solved the first part. The next part will be a continuation, so make  sure you solve the first part. I have also written a poem, I hope you find it fun reading :-
>
> Behold, for when you see the stars behind the moon, 
> You will find this puzzle difficult very soon. 
> Ignore the bright ones, look at the dark. 
> Try to use my clues, and the dark will spark. 
> Your eyes mustn't look random, the constellations you see, 
> The sight is a lot beautiful than it must be. 
> But that's not all, look for the stars that do not fly. 
> Ignore gravity, these ones will not go very high. 
> Time is running up, count them before blue becomes the sky.

That is surely some sort of a masterpiece writing. I did not know my sister had so much knowledge on literature. I felt quite pleased with these workings she had done for me, and I proceed reading the last letter.

> Hi, stuck on the puzzle? I knew you would, because I have not made it easy, especially the second note  that you read.
>
> Here's another part of the third note, this is just a hint of the second note and nothing new. Hope you like it.
>
> My prefix is a verb, can also be very excessive. 
> My infix is a verb as well, but used with u. 
> My suffix is used to specify a period of time. 
> My next-to-next suffix has a great vertical extent.
>
> Can you guess what I am? 
> Just to make things easier for you, I am looking for a word as the final solution of the puzzle. Let me know if you solved it or not!

My brain is dozing after reading all of these. Can you, solve these series of puzzles?

It will be better if full answers are posted, I would not like partial answers.

**Note**: This is my first attempt in making a series of puzzles, hope you guys enjoy solving it, let me know if you liked it or not.

**Hint 1**:

> The Nonogram will be required in the next part of the puzzle.

**Hint 2**:

> The answer is already mentioned in the puzzle.

**Hint 3**:

> (Continuation of note 3) :- My next-to-next prefix never loses anything.

**Hint 4**:

> Try to relate the second letter, and the third letter together. Both should give the same answer.

**Hint 5**:

> nJtpuMR
>
>  ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)

**Big Hint (big enough to proceed)**:

> The third letter does not deal with words.

**Big Hint 2**:

> Take a look at Hint 3 again, still stuck figuring out the answer?

**Big Hint 3**:

> Can you find a number in the Nonogram? If yes, can you relate it with the second letter? If yes, how will you do it?

If you are stuck with Big Hint 3, here's another hint.

**Big Hint 4**:

> The answer starts with a consonant and ends with a double set of a certain vowel.

**For Those who are having Problems what next-to-next prefix or next-to-next suffix mean**:-

> Take an example like a word "shopkeeper" . The suffix would be "keeper" and next-to-next suffix would be "per" , given that per is also a meaningful word.  If you consider the prefixes, then "shop" would be the prefix, and "hop" would be the next-to-next prefix.

> Here's another thing to note down, if you are trying to solve this puzzle, you might have to think a bit creative in this case. :P

**Note**:- Since this puzzle was posted a month ago and is still not answered, I want to inform that partial answers are accepted, but in the end I want this whole puzzle to be solved.

Comment: I solved the nono gram, do you want me to show a step by step?

Comment: @Smartest1here , there's more to solve, not just that. It's better to give the complete solution first. The answer is a word.

Comment: What do you mean by next to next suffix?

Comment: I won't give hints, try thinking. I will give hints in the post when it is time

Comment: You might want to state then no partial answers.

Comment: (I think the nonogram is straightforward enough that there's no need to step-by-step it.)

Comment: Can you explain what next-to-next suffix means it seems highly ambigious, and I don't this is intentional.

Comment: Think of it as a word which has 2 suffices, and the next-to-next suffix would be the 2nd suffix of that word. You might also need to think a bit creative in this case.

Comment: Hi Anonymous, I will re-post my solution, then can you tell me exactly where I am wrong?

Comment: If I would have told, then the puzzle would be 50% solved.

Comment: rot13(Vavgvnyyl V gubhtug gur frpbaq yrggre jbhyq svg cresrpgyl va gur "tncf" yrsg ol gur svefg gb znxr n jbeq, cuenfr, be pyhr (guvax Jurry bs Sbeghar).  Ohg gurer ner gbb znal jbeqf naq yvarf sbe gung gb or vg.  Gura V gubhtug znlor gur cnggreaf ner bs pbafgryyngvbaf, ohg V pna'g znxr frafr bs gung rvgure.  V unir bar cbffvoyr thrff gung xvaq bs svgf.)

Comment: @mjjf rot13(Nf n pbzzrag V jbhyq nqivfr lbh bayl bar guvat, guvax zber! V nccerpvngr ubj lbh ner gelvat qvssrerag jnlf gb gel gur chmmyr lrg abguvat pbzrf gb lbhe zvaq, ohg orsber gelvat ntnva, V jbhyq nqivfr lbh gb ybbx ng gur uvagf naq gura nggnpx ntnva. Fbeel sbe gur yngr pbzzrag, gubhtu.)

Comment: I'm still not sure what a next-to-next suffix or next-to-next prefix are. Can you give an example?

Comment: @hexomino Take an example like a word "shopkeeper" . The suffix would be "keeper" and next-to-next suffix would be "per" , given that per is also a meaningful word. Here's another thing to note down, you might have to think a bit creative in this case. If you consider the prefixes, then "shop" would be the prefix, and "hop" would be the next-to-next prefix.

Comment: @Anonymous Ah, okay, that makes things clear - I had thought the next-to-next prefix would be "sh".

Comment: @Anonymous In both your examples, the "next-to-next" affix is at the end of the original affix (sHOP and keePER) - is this consistent with how it would be used for this puzzle? I was thinking that "next-to-next suffix" meant "second last suffix" (ie. keep) and that "next-to-next prefix" would be "second prefix" (ie. hop, as in the example)

Comment: @samm82 next-to-next suffix means the next suffix after the suffix, why would it be the second last suffix? Nevermind, the next-to-next suffix would be "per" only. In terms of prefix, you are considering the prefixes from the starting letters of the word, so the prefix is "shop" , and next-to-next prefix is "hop" .



(Another thing to note down. you might have to think a bit creative in this case, consider these prefixes and suffixes bit creative, and then work on the problem, take the hints to your use.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note**:- After the Community told me to answer my own question, I am finally answering it. Also I would love to get some feedback on the puzzle itself, as well as the answer.
Thank You!!

Check the Spoiler for the Answer:-

> Three

Before Moving to the First Letter, you need to check **Big Hint 4** first.

**First Letter** (Solving the Nonogram):-

> [image]

> This was the easiest part of the puzzle, the Nonogram is pretty straightforward and I don't think I need to explain this. I am just giving the answer.

> Although many will solve the Nonogram, I was able to see that almost none was able to notice something peculiar. I will reveal this by posting another picture:-

> [image]

> There was already a 2021 hiding in it, and if you track the time when I send this puzzle, it was 4th Jan 2021, probably reasonable of why there's a 2021 if you know. Moreover, **Hint 5** is actually the link going to an Imgur Page, and that mentions that "The Puzzle was posted on 4th Jan 2021", trying to make you notice that there's a "2021" hidden in the Nonogram.

After this, I made it tough to progress to the second and third letter, although I did not expect it to be very tough even after giving hints.

**Moving to the Second Letter** (The Poem Puzzle):-

> This was the hardest part of the puzzle. I made the meanings so hard that no one was able to answer this (although @Gareth tried a lot, I admire him for that). I will explain each line of the poem.

> Behold, for when you see the stars behind the moon, 
> You will find this puzzle difficult very soon.

> Taking help from **Hint 1**, you will need the Nonogram for this puzzle. This actually is true, since these two lines are referring to the "stars" as the shaded boxes of the Nonogram, and this is more like another hint of spotting the "2021" mainly because one cannot notice stars behind the moon (or the moon is transparent).

> Ignore the bright ones, look at the dark. 
> Try to use my clues, and the dark will spark.

> I meant to add this to say that you have to check clues from the dark squares, with full concentration. The "dark will spark" is more like a pun, saying that if you can find out the idea what I mean from the clues, you will get the answer.

> Your eyes mustn't look random, the constellations you see,
> The sight is a lot beautiful than it must be.

> The constellation, of course, refers to the "2021" hidden. Imagine the sky to be the Nonogram, and the "stars" to be the shaded squares. The "2021" will be a fine constellation to watch. Next, "Your eyes mustn't look random" means that you need not think about the other bits for your answer, your eyes must be focused on the "2021" only. The second line is just added to rhyme the first line and is of no specific use.

> But that's not all, look for the stars that do not fly.
> Ignore gravity, these ones will not go very high.
> Time is running up, count them before blue becomes the sky.

> This is the most trickiest part, no one was able to get it, and so no one was able to find the answer. This is referring to all those stars, which are not flying, or ignoring gravity on the Nonogram. Some thought as the 7 dark squares under the Nonogram, but if that would be the case, the third letter would not make sense. There's however, another idea, which works. For that I have to show a picture:-

> [image]

> Notice the blue squares, if you consider the Constellation "2021" to be a barrier, then those 3 blue squares seem to be ignoring gravity (in the sky if might not look like so), but here, it definitely ignores gravity. The third line says to count the number of stars which have those ability, so the answer is three. Note that from **Hint 2**, the answer is already mentioned at least once in the puzzle.

> From **Hint 4**, it might not look that obvious that the third letter should also have the answer "three", but from a creative way, you will see that is the case too. (I don't know how much it is creative).

**Moving To Third Letter (Affix Riddle):-**

> My prefix is a verb, can also be very excessive.

> The most unusual thing is, there are no prefix for three. But is that so? Check **Big Hint 1** first, the answer does not deal with words. So what is three, 3 is a number! Now, from a creative way, prefix of 3 would be 2. 2 can be spelled as "two" , which is a homophone of "too" or "to". "To" is a verb, and "too" can mean excessive, like "too" much.

> My infix is a verb as well, but used with u.

> Note that "u" refers to "you" here. Here the infix of 3 is referring to the letter "r" in "three". Also note that "r" is referred to as "are", and obviously "are" is a verb mainly used with "you"

> My suffix is used to specify a period of time.

> Here, from the fact we used with the prefix, the suffix of 3 is 4. Four here is a homophone of "for" or "fore", but "for" is a preposition which specifies a period of time.

> My next-to-next suffix has a great vertical extent.

> Here's another tricky part, what I meant by next-to-next suffix in the question, has a different meaning to this one. This means the next-to-next suffix of 3, is actually going to be the suffix of 4, which is 5. And note that by "a great vertical extent", I mean a "High Five", "High" is used to mean something having a great vertical extent, in that sense. (I hope this makes sense, although it's a bit vague).

> (From **Hint 3**):- My next-to-next prefix never loses anything.

> Here, next-to-next prefix of 3 will be the prefix of 2, which is 1. "One" is the homophone of "Won", and the meaning is exactly opposite to that of "Lose". So do you expect it to lose?

So this is it, the full explanation of the Puzzle. Let me know if you liked it or not.
Other Hints specify the answer only:- 
i) **Hint 2** mentions the answer is present to the puzzle, which is true. 
ii) **Big Hint 2** actually reveals the answer, but to play a trick I said to look on "Hint 3", because the number "3" is present. 
iii) **Big Hint 4** gives some details of the answer. The answer is "three", "t" is a consonant and it ends with a double set of the vowel "e".

Comment: A few things that jump out - "too" is not a verb. Also the way you defined next-to-next prefix in the hint is inconsistent, you defined it as the suffix of the prefix. Also what is "nJtpuMR"?

Comment: @hexomino "too" is not a verb but "to" is . For the words sequence it is actually reasonable to consider next-to-next prefix the suffix of the prefix, for this numbers sequence I think it is obvious what next-to-next prefix will be. Also "nJtpuMR" is the letters of the link going to the imgur page.

Comment: "to" isn't a verb either. I disagree with your second sentence, it's not obvious at all, that's why I asked - the obvious thing would be that the words and numbers are analogous. Can you put it the specific link, please, because I keep getting a 404 on imgur with this address?

Comment: @hexomino seems to work fine for me: https://imgur.com/a/nJtpuMR

Comment: @oAlt Ah, thank you, this may be my lack of familiarity with imgur. What is the "/a" directory and how do we know to append this?

Comment: Next time please just use a i.stack.imgur URL, I see no reason to not use it in this case, I'd argue everyone is familiar with the URL format and we consider i.stack.imgur urls self-contained, while we do not necessarily do that for normal imgur links.

Comment: OK, here are some comments as requested (and as promised in my answer to OP's meta question).

Comment: For the second letter, it never occurred to me that "count them" might be literally the last step leading to the answer, so I was looking for combinations of "stars" with, so to speak, more information in them. (This one's my fault; I should have considered taking "count them" as meaning exactly what it said and no more.)

Comment: And of course it never occurred to me to interpret the verse the way you intended; aside from my own lack of creativity, I think one issue is that the metaphors here don't make sense. These stars are meant to be ... resting on top of the "2021"? But why would they do that if we "ignore gravity"? And didn't you just describe the digits of 2021 as "constellations"? What sense would it mean for stars to rest on top of other stars? How can you say "not very high" when one of them is literally on the top row of the nonogram?

Comment: I also thought the "up" in "Time is running up" might be significant, since the usual idiom is "running _down_". (Some of your hints were about spotting the 2021 in the first place; _that_ was immediately obvious to me.)

Comment: For the third letter, I agree with hexomino's comments. Also, while the idea of making a Riley-type puzzle that's not referring to decomposing words is a clever one, I don't think this is quite fair, because "prefix" and "suffix" don't mean "thing that comes before" and "thing that comes after"; 4 simply _isn't_ a suffix of 3.

Comment: The "next-to-next" business is particularly vexing, though I can't claim it stopped me solving the puzzle since I never thought of the possibility of interpreting it in terms of elements of a sequence. "Next-to-next" isn't an idiom in English, so we had to rely on your explanations in the hints to know what it means; and those explanations _are fundamentally different_ from what it turns out you actually meant.

Comment: Many of the clues and hints are difficult to make use of because in some sense they involve one layer of indirection too many. For instance, "My next-to-next suffix has a great vertical extent". To make use of this, you need to think of "high" (which is not unreasonable), then think of the "located skyward" meaning and _not_ the "large vertical extent" meaning (because a "high five" _doesn't_ have large vertical extent, it's just further _up_ than e.g. a handshake), then think of "high five", then think of "five" as some sort of double-suffix of "three".

Comment: Imagine the process of solving this sort of puzzle as one where you start with a number of points in some kind of abstract concept-space -- "great vertical extent", "never loses anything", etc. -- and you're trying to find connections between them. So you hop from one place in concept-space to another, and if you're lucky you eventually find two paths that lead close enough to one another for you to notice. You can realistically do this if the time it takes to do the exploration isn't excessive.

Comment: But that amount of time grows exponentially as the number of steps you need to take from each starting point to where they meet increases. And if the number isn't quite small, the chances are you'll just hop around for ever without finding anything.

Comment: When you're _setting_ rather than _solving_ a puzzle, one extra mental step doesn't feel like much. After all, you know what the intended path is, and surely a five-step path is only 25% more work than a four-step path. No! For the _solver_, who doesn't know what the intended path is, every step _multiplies_ the amount of required exploration by a substantial factor.

Comment: This is one reason why precision is important in riddles (I don't mean that riddles can't be ambiguous, obscure, etc., but that any _unintended_ imprecision can be a big problem). Every extra bit of vagueness adds more mental steps, or alternatively greatly increases the range of possible next steps, and therefore makes the puzzle much harder. (In a way that's less satisfying for the solver than getting past more _deliberately placed_ steps, too.) It's why making riddles in what isn't your native language is really difficult: one or two slip-ups can make the puzzle entirely unfair.

Comment: The other thing about most of the clues and hints -- which isn't in itself necessarily a problem, but again makes them harder to make use of -- is that they almost all only make any sense once you have at least an inkling what the answer is going to be. E.g., your "big hint 2": OK, once you know the answer is literally "three" you might figure out the misdirection there. But before you know that? No! "Look again at hint 3" means look again at hint 3, it doesn't mean "the number 3 is significant".

Comment: I don't mean that clues/hints of this sort are always bad. In most riddles, at least some of the clues are like this. But when they're all you've got, it can be difficult to make progress. Suppose I say "I'm thinking of a book" and then start giving you clues like "page 56, line 3, 17th letter is R". After I've given, say, a dozen such clues, I've almost certainly told you enough that there's only one book in the world fitting the clues. But they're _no help at all_ in actually finding it.

Comment: Oh ... and I think it's kinda unfair to have "prefix" and "suffix" mean "previous number" and "next number" but then have "infix" mean "letter in the middle of the word".

Comment: ( @hexomino I'm sorry for I don't have the slightest idea about it either)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Your book example is actually a very nice idea in cryptology (: And I'm also kind of disappointed after seeing this answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is the answer to the first letter (you can swap the black and white):

> [image]

I’m not sure on the next part, though

Comment: There's more to solve.

Comment: Is the coloring correct here?

Comment: @personaelit if you know how to solve Nonograms, then yep it is.